# How to use the deliver method to send a short message using opensmpp?

Tags: java, smpp, opensmpp

I use opensmpp and try the submit method (Submit_SM) and it work fine. But later i discover that i must use the deliver method (Deliver_SM) in order to use the listener side of the ESME and receive the message from the SMSC.
Here is my code the bind work fine but the response from the deliver method is always null.
Please if anyone can help me or at least give me a little example whith the deliver method
PS: I use the synchronous mode.

```
import org.smpp.pdu.BindRequest
import org.smpp.pdu.BindResponse
import org.smpp.pdu.BindTransciever
import org.smpp.pdu.BindTransmitter
import org.smpp.pdu.BindReceiver
import org.smpp.TCPIPConnection
import org.smpp.Session
import org.smpp.test.SMPPTest.SMPPTestPDUEventListener
import org.smpp.pdu.AddressRange
import org.smpp.Data
import org.smpp.pdu.UnbindResp
import org.smpp.pdu.DeliverSM
import org.smpp.pdu.DataSM
import org.smpp.pdu.DeliverSMResp
import org.smpp.pdu.DataSMResp
import org.smpp.pdu.PDU
import org.smpp.pdu.Request
import org.smpp.pdu.Response
import org.smpp.ServerPDUEvent
import org.smpp.pdu.Address
import org.smpp.pdu.EnquireLink
import org.smpp.pdu.EnquireLinkResp

Session session = null;
def bound = false
boolean asynchronous = false;
String bindOption = "tr";
String systemType = "";
String serviceType = "";
Address sourceAddress = new Address()
Address destAddress = new Address()
byte replaceIfPresentFlag = 0;
String shortMessage = ""; // the message to send
String scheduleDeliveryTime = "";
String validityPeriod = "" // default estimated validity default period
byte esmClass = 0;
byte protocolId = 0;
byte priorityFlag = 0;
byte registeredDelivery = 0;
byte dataCoding = 0;
byte smDefaultMsgId = 0;
String messageId = "";
long receiveTimeout = Data.RECEIVE_BLOCKING;
AddressRange addressRange = new AddressRange();
SMPPTestPDUEventListener pduListener = null;

    println "begin binding operation..."
    try {

        // test if communication is already established
        if (bound) {
            System.out.println("Already bound, unbind first.");
            return;
        }

        BindRequest request = null;
        BindResponse response = null;
        // type of the session
        String syncMode = (asynchronous ? "a" : "s");

        // input values


        if (bindOption.compareToIgnoreCase("t") == 0) {
            request = new BindTransmitter();
        } else if (bindOption.compareToIgnoreCase("r") == 0) {
            request = new BindReceiver();
        } else if (bindOption.compareToIgnoreCase("tr") == 0) {
            request = new BindTransciever();
        }

        ipAddress = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";
        port = yyyy;

        println "syncMode == "+syncMode
        TCPIPConnection connection = new TCPIPConnection(ipAddress, port);
        connection.setReceiveTimeout(20 * 1000);
        session = new Session(connection);

        systemId = "nnnnnn"
        password = "nnnnnn"

        // set values
        request.setSystemId(systemId);
        request.setPassword(password);
        request.setSystemType(systemType);
        request.setInterfaceVersion((byte) 0x34);
        request.setAddressRange(addressRange);

        // send the request
        System.out.println("Bind request " + request.debugString());
        if (asynchronous) {
            pduListener = new SMPPTestPDUEventListener(session);
            response = session.bind(request, pduListener);
        } else {
            response = session.bind(request);
        }
        System.out.println("Bind response " + response.debugString());
        println "response.getCommandStatus() === "+response.getCommandStatus()
        if (response.getCommandStatus() == Data.ESME_ROK) {
            bound = true;
            println "SMSC is bound succesfuuly with the ESME"
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //event.write(e, "");
        //debug.write("Bind operation failed. " + e);
        System.out.println("Bind operation failed. " + e);
    } finally {
        //session.unbind()
        //connection.close()
    }

    println "enquire data ... "
    try {
        final EnquireLink request = new EnquireLink();
        System.out.println("Enquire Link request " + request.debugString());
        final EnquireLinkResp response = session.enquireLink(request);
        System.out.println("Enquire Link response " + response.debugString());
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


try {
    DeliverSM request = new DeliverSM();
    DeliverSMResp response;

            // input values
            serviceType = ""
            sourceAddress.setNpi((byte)1)
    sourceAddress.setTon((byte)1)
    sourceAddress.setAddress("4123601", Data.SM_ADDR_LEN)
            destAddress.setNpi((byte)1)
    destAddress.setTon((byte)1)
    destAddress.setAddress("0022233411686", Data.SM_ADDR_LEN)
            esmClass = 0
            registeredDelivery = 0;
            dataCoding = 0;

           // set values
    request.setServiceType(serviceType);
            request.setSequenceNumber(1)
    request.setSourceAddr(sourceAddress);
    request.setDestAddr(destAddress);
    request.setEsmClass(esmClass);
    request.setRegisteredDelivery(registeredDelivery);
    request.setDataCoding(dataCoding);
            request.setProtocolId(protocolId)
            request.setPriorityFlag(priorityFlag);
            request.setShortMessage("Hello world",Data.ENC_ASCII);

    // send the request
    System.out.println("Data request " + request.debugString());
    if (asynchronous) {
        session.data(request);
    } else {
        response = session.deliver(request); // here the problem , the response is always null
        System.out.println("Data response " + response.debugString());
        messageId = response.getMessageId();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Data operation failed. " + e);
    }
finally {
       session.unbind()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using 'PDU response = session.receive(0)' instead of 'response = session.deliver(request)'. The parameter 0 means no wait for an answer, so it can return null. But, when the deliver arrived you will have it. Later, you will have to process the response:

```
        int commandId = pdu.getCommandId();

        switch(commandId) {
            case Data.DELIVER_SM:
                DeliverSM pduDeliver = (DeliverSM)pdu;
                procesarDeliver(pduDeliver);
                break;

            case Data.ENQUIRE_LINK:
                //Do something
                break;

            case Data.UNBIND:
                //Do something
                break;

            default:
                //Do something
                break;
        }
```

I'm sorry for my english.... ;)